# Does Kubernetes ConfigMap is only for Pods and Deployments?

Tags: kubernetes

It's a simple question - is there a way to use ConfigMap key-values in, let's say - Ingress?

I want to have the configuration of such things in one place, to make it easier to clone the whole cluster.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

ConfigMap is for usage in a pod to supply configuration at runtime. The recommendation is any deployment yaml including ingress and configMaps should be stored in a version control system. That way you can apply to a new cluster whenever needed. You can go one step further and adopt what is called [GitOps](https://www.weave.works/technologies/gitops/).